# Compare 2 dataTable which are linked with primary Key in c# using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I want to use `id` as primary key and 2 tables must be linked with this primary key. Result must be like this

1. it first checks with primary key if it exists in second table or not
2. updated data associated based on key

Code:

```
 DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Table1");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Id",typeof(int)); 
    dt1.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Occupation");

    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Table2");
    dt2.Columns.Add("Id",typeof(int));
    dt2.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt2.Columns.Add("Occupation");

    DataTable Final = dt1.AsEnumerable()
                         .Except(dt2.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default)
                         .CopyToDataTable();

[I need the result to be like this][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/brqCF.jpg


new Code : 







DataTable dtFinal = new DataTable();

        DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();
        dtNew.Columns.Add("Id");
        dtNew.Columns.Add("Name");
        dtNew.Rows.Add("1", "Yash Fale");
        dtNew.Rows.Add("3", "Rahul");


        DataTable dtOld = new DataTable();
        dtOld.Columns.Add("Id");
        dtOld.Columns.Add("Name");
        dtOld.Rows.Add("1", "Yash");
        dtOld.Rows.Add("2", "pops");


        var addOrUpdateRecords =
                                (from drNew in dtNew.AsEnumerable()
                                 join drOld in dtOld.AsEnumerable() on drNew.Field<string>("Id") equals drOld.Field<string>("Id") into match
                                 from drOld in match.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 where drOld == null /* new */ || !DataRowComparer.Default.Equals(drNew, drOld) /* changed */
                                 select drNew).ToList();
            if (addOrUpdateRecords.Any())
                dtFinal = addOrUpdateRecords.CopyToDataTable();

        // i want to add new column like as Status for below condition 
        // for added Records = status : newRecord
        // for updated Records = status : UpdatedRecord


        //OutPut : ie. dtFinal
        // ID Name Status
        //  1  Yash Fale UpdatedRecord
        //  3  Rahul     newRecord
```

Comment: Your tables have the same name, is this a copy/paste error or are you joining the same table to itself?

Comment: So, you want a list of Ids that exist in `Table1` and not `Table2` so you can then update `Table1`?

Comment: I dont understand the requirement. _" updated data associated based on key"_ What is the updated data and what do you want to keep? It's also not clear why i should check thst  link.

Comment: ya actually i want to link both datatable with primary key , and then it check is there is any new id , then it pick it , and also check for row data is updated for particular id , if yes then it picks that row also

Comment: @yashfale: that means you don't know how to link two tables via primary/foreign-key? What rows do you want to keep, table1 or table2, what is the updated data? Provide sample data and a desired result.

Comment: @tim check the image i have just added  http://i.stack.imgur.com/brqCF.jpg

Comment: So you want rows from table 2 if either a) the id doesn't exist in table 1 or b) the id exists in table 1 but one or more items of data is different?

Comment: @chris above code is working well but result must be based on linked primary key , means there will be no duplication in result table

Comment: can't you consider only 2 columns "Name" & "Occupation" and create new ids in new table? will this work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LINQ operator for correlating two sequences by some criteria is called [join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx).

Let rename your `dt1` to `dtOld` and `dt2` to `dtNew`.

The added records can be determined by joining `dtNew` to `dtOld` on `Id` field using the [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) and filtering the records from `dtNew` that have no matching record in `dtOld`:

```
var addRecords =
    (from drNew in dtNew.AsEnumerable()
     join drOld in dtOld.AsEnumerable() on drNew.Field<int>("Id") equals drOld.Field<int>("Id") into match
     where !match.Any()
     select drNew).ToList();
```

Note that the above produces a `List<DataRecord>`. `CopyToDataTable` call fails when the passed sequence is empty, so if you really need data tables, use something like this:

```
var dtAdd = addRecords.Any() ? addRecords.CopyToDataTable() : null;
```

Determining the deleted records is exactly the same, just `dtOld` and `dtNew` are exchanged:

```
var deleteRecords =
    (from drOld in dtOld.AsEnumerable()
     join drNew in dtNew.AsEnumerable() on drOld.Field<int>("Id") equals drNew.Field<int>("Id") into match
     where !match.Any()
     select drOld).ToList();
```

Finally, the modified records can be retrieved by using a [inner join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) and filtering the matching records that differ (the handy `DataRowComparer.Default` can be used to compare the data row values):

```
var updateRecords =
    (from drNew in dtNew.AsEnumerable()
     join drOld in dtOld.AsEnumerable() on drNew.Field<int>("Id") equals drOld.Field<int>("Id")
     where !DataRowComparer.Default.Equals(drNew, drOld)
     select drNew).ToList();
```

**Update:** For completeness, here is how you can retrieve new and modified records with one query, this time using [left outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx):

```
var addOrUpdateRecords =
    (from drNew in dtNew.AsEnumerable()
     join drOld in dtOld.AsEnumerable() on drNew.Field<int>("Id") equals drOld.Field<int>("Id") into match
     from drOld in match.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where drOld == null /* new */ || !DataRowComparer.Default.Equals(drNew, drOld) /* changed */
     select drNew).ToList();
```

Comment: above code is working well, can we have common linq query for updateRecords and addRecords ? , i tried and googled but failed.

Comment: Actually it's possible, however I don't know how you will distinguish them later.

Comment: awesome ,code is working well , thank you @Ivan Stoev

Comment: i want to add status column if newRecod then status will be newRecord else if updated record then status updated record , is it possible with addOrUpdateRecords one query

Comment: In the last query (the single one), at the end you have that information, so for instance you could do something like `select new { Record = drNew, Status = drOld == null ? StatusEnum.New : StatusEnum.Updated }`